# Hive - 4 table join

Tags: performance, hadoop, hive

I need to join 4 tables and in each join condition join columns are different

Data Size

```
Table emp - 8T
Table stu - 10GB
Table college - 800 MB
Table address - 2 TB
```

Query -

```
select a.*,b.*,c.*,d.* from emp  a 
Left outer join stu b(a.id=b.id)
left outer join college  c(a.trans_id=c.trans_id and a.emp_id=c.emp_id)
left outer join address  d(a.seq_no=d.seq_no and a.emp_id=d.emp_id )
```

The execution time of above query is too high as using heavy dataset.

Is there any way to increase the performance

Answer (score 0):

Hive's performance can be increased by using [Tez](https://tez.apache.org/) as an execution engine.

Depending on whether or not you are using a platform that comes with Hive pre-installed, or have a vanilla installation you may or may not have Tez already.

If not, Tez installation instructions can be found here: [Install/Deploy Instructions for Tez](https://tez.apache.org/install.html)

In order to use Tez you will need to preface your query with:
`set hive.execution.engine=tez;`

In my testing (3 node cluster) I experienced a 25% performance gain on average.

Comment: we are not using tez and that is also not in plan, is there any other way, I tried several properties from hive but nothing is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to tune your query :

1. Using Tez engine.
2. Better file formats for each tables, especially the larger ones.
3. Add CBO, vectorization properties
4. Number of mappers, reducers, volume of each map tasks, reduce tasks , map output compression properties.
5. You could also modify your query in such a way that your largest table is the second table in your join query.i.e `select a.* from tabA a join tabB b on a.id=b.id` . Here TabB should be larger than the tabA.

You could refer [this](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.5.5/bk_hive-performance-tuning/bk_hive-performance-tuning.pdf) document for more details on optimization.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use TEZ. Tez performs faster than MR.

`set hive.execution.engine=tez;`

2. Try to decrease bytes per reducer. Decreasing this parameter will increase parallelizm (the number of reducers)

`hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=67108864;`

3. Use Vectorization

`set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = true;
 set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled = true;`

4. Your tables are really big. If possible reduce number of data. For example join only new/recently updated records.